# GDI+ in Windows NT 4.0 SP6

Tags: windows-nt-4, gdi

I create a Script using Autoit that needs **GDI+** to work.
How can I install GDI+ in **Windows NT 4.0** SP6?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to find `gdiplus.dll` and put it into operating system
folder, which is probably `C:\WINNT\System32`.

You might find this DLL here:

[originaldll.com gdiplus.dll](http://originaldll.com/file/gdiplus.dll/17096.html)

Otherwise, you will need to find it on the Internet.

Comment: Might I ask for the reason of the downvote?

Comment: Thanks. I was found & copy the gdiplus.dll file to system32 folder, but my script that needs the gdi+ terminates! It seems to be needed in another way...

Comment: Any indication why it terminates, and how?